# jQuery FadeOut many divs at once

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I am trying to fade out multiple divs at once and fade in one div after that completes.  Here's the code:

```
if($(this).attr("id")==="benefits-button"){

    $("#solar-about, #home-page, #process-page, #financing-page, #vendors-page, #consump-info-page, #smart-page, #wind-page, #about-page").fadeOut(750, function() {
         $("#benefits-page").fadeIn(750);
    });
    }
```

When there are multiple divs in the selector, the fadeOut and fadeIn happen at the same time.

**Question:** How do I get the fadeIn after the fadeOut?

Thank you

Comment: So..what is the question?

Comment: why not using `class` instead of too many `id`s?

Comment: @Raminson your comment is actually the Answer™.

Comment: @Marc: "A does not work. A* does." The implied question is probably, "why does A not work if A* does and how do I get it to work the same way?"

Comment: Basically, I am trying to fade out multiple divs at once and fade in one div after that completes.  The code above will fadeIn as it is fading out

Comment: Have you tried to use `.stop()` before `.fadeOut(` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("#benefits-page").fadeIn(750);
```

is working immediately because it's starting to work when the first element (#solar-about in your example) fadeOut animation is completed.

If you want to wait until all animations are completed than you can use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), like this:

```
$("#solar-about, #home-page, #process-page, #financing-page, #vendors-page, #consump-info-page, #smart-page, #wind-page, #about-page").fadeOut(750).promise().done(function() {
     $("#benefits-page").fadeIn(750);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GE72B/)